# How to write XPATH for getting below element text?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-2.0

i'm trying to write xpath for below span element.
any idea?

```html
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line " role="presentation">
    <span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;">Status Code  : 200 OK</span></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//span[@role='presentation']
```

Or

```
//*[@class='CodeMirror-line ' and (@role='presentation)']/span[@role='presentation']
```

To get the element text you can do this:

```
response_el_xpath = "//span[@role='presentation']"
response_status = driver.find_element_by_xpath(response_el_xpath).text
```

Comment: actually i'm trying to get the "Status Code  : 200 OK" value using his XPATH. AND //span[@role='presentation'] is not unique its having many results.

Comment: With Selenium ?

Comment: some other automation tool, but its based on Selenium.

Comment: I suggested you are using Python. If you are using other language it will be quite similar.

Comment: I also suggested you have some wait / delay before getting that element.

Comment: if `//span[@role='presentation'] ` is not unique we need to see more HTML code of that page, preferably to see the entire page, preferably to get a link to the page...

Comment: Does `//*[@class='CodeMirror-line ' and (@role='presentation)']/span[@role='presentation']` unique locator or not too?

Comment: i tried this and it seems fine for now:   //*[contains(text(),'200 OK')] thanks for your help :)

Comment: What if the response status will change?

Answer (score 0):

This question can't be answered from the information given.

Firstly, to find an element uniquely within a page, we need a condition that is true for that element, but false for all other elements, and we can't establish this without knowing what else is on the page (plus the context of the element you wish to find).

Secondly, if you knew exactly what was on the page, you wouldn't need XPath to search it. You only need XPath because you know something about the structure of the page, but you don't know everything about its content. So you need to tell us not only what the page looks like, but which aspects of the page you can assume to be fixed, and which aspects you must assume to be variable.